# Duplicate Entry Types into a new section

Tags: entry-type

Is there a way to duplicate Entry Types into a new section?  I have a section with many entry types with their fields and handles all named nicely...  I need to create a Section using exactly the same Entry Type setup?

Many thanks

Martin

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a plugin to do this. I've used [the architect](https://github.com/Pennebaker/craftcms-thearchitect) for doing exactly this in the past. Just export the section and entry types you want to duplicate, rename the section in the json file, delete everything except for the section and entry type definitions, and import.